# Struts execute() not being called but ActionSupport's execute() is called instead

Tags: struts2, struts

I am using struts 2 together with the convention plugin and am seeing strange behaviour. The execute() of my class is not being called but the execute() in the superclass ActionSupport is being called instead. Thus my business logic is not being executed. In this example, the message attribute obtained in the view is null. When I tried to abandon the convention plugin and declared the action in struts.xml, it worked fine. Below is my code.

```
public class HelloAction extends ActionSupport {

    private String message;

    @Override
    public String execute() {
        message = new Date().toString();
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks and regards,

M Cachia

Comment: are you using xml file for the configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing to do with the given code, its working fine in my system and the controller going into the execute() method HelloAction class. I used below xml configuration its working  fine.

```
<action name="test" class="com.HelloAction">
  <result>/jsp/results.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Please check with the configuration file.